# call javascript function onchange event of dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html

I want to invoke javascript function when value in the dropdown list changes. *I dont want to hardcode dropdown list id* .

Hence not using `document.getElementById`

My Code:

```
<select id ="ddl" name="ddl" onmousedown="this.value='';" onchange="jsFunction(this.value);">
  <option value='1'>One</option>
  <option value='2'>Two</option>
  <option value='3'>Three</option>
</select>

function jsFunction(value)
{
    alert(value);
}
```

This is giving error `ReferenceError: jsFunction is not defined`

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6uyz4b8x/1/

Comment: [want this](http://jsfiddle.net/6uyz4b8x/2/)? You have to update fiddle settings change the 2nd dropdown to **nowrap in <head>** to fidddle!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your code is working just fine, you have to declare javscript method before DOM ready.

[image: your working example]

Answer (score 20):

I don't know why do you need this `onmousedown` event here, but what you have to do is put your function above actual usage. Look at the snipplet below:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function jsFunction(value)
{
    alert(value);
}
</script>

<select id ="ddl" name="ddl" onmousedown="this.value='';" onchange="jsFunction(this.value);">
  <option value='1'>One</option>
  <option value='2'>Two</option>
  <option value='3'>Three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 16):

using jQuery

```
 $("#ddl").change(function () {
                alert($(this).val());
            });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vhswj9jq/1/)

Comment: What if I want to get the text of the selection too. I tried `$(this).text()` but it shows all the texts for all the dropdown for every single click.

Answer (score 5):

You just try this, Its so easy

```
 <script>

  $("#YourDropDownId").change(function () {
            alert($("#YourDropDownId").val());
        });

</script>
```

Comment: How to get the text too

Comment: @Unbreakable : 
`var e = document.getElementById("YourDropDownId"); 
var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;`

Answer (score 2):

jsFunction is not in good closure. change to:

```
jsFunction = function(value)
{
    alert(value);
}
```

and don't use global variables and functions, change it into [module](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/)

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. Your answer just gives good advice.

Comment: Weird... It actually does. Sorry about that ;)

Comment: it works because this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Comment: How to get the text also