# onChange event in javascript is not triggering in select box

Tags: javascript, php

I'm sorry to ask a duplicate question again but i'm really got into this...

Down there is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function textHint()
    {
       Confirm("Do u want to proceed");
     }
  </script>
  <select name="duration" id="duration"  class="inp_bx" onChange="textHint();"> 
      <option value="1">-Select-</option>
        <?php
        $sql = "select distinct(package_type) from tbl_package";
        $retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn );
        if(! $retval )
         {
          die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
          echo 'Could not get data: ' . mysql_error();
          }
         while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval,MYSQL_ASSOC))
         {
            $package= $row['package_type'];?>   
            <option value="<?php echo $package?>"><?php echo $package;?>     
            </option>
        <?php } ?>
   </select>
```

I'm getting the value in select box from database but the onchange  function is not triggering out...i dont know why?

This is similar to the one on the link:

[call javascript function onchange event of dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26709969/call-javascript-function-onchange-event-of-dropdown-list)

Instead the value is fetched from the database...

Thanks in advance guys...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is case-sensitive. Your `Confirm` should be `confirm`.

```
function textHint()
{
   confirm("Do u want to proceed");
}
```